# Best datatype to store postal codes in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqldatatypes

I'm new to Oracle, I'm using oracle 11g. I'm storing postal codes of UK. Values are like these.

```
 N22 5HF

 SW1 4JD

 N14 8IT

 N22 1JT

 E1 5DP

 e1 8DS

 E3 8TU
```

I should be able to easily compare **first four characters of each postal code**. 
What is the best `data type` to store these data ?

Comment: Do you really mean the first four characters, or [the outward code](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_postcodes#Outward_code)? Are the values always properly formatted?

Comment: @AlexPoole Now I read about outward code, yes it's outward code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a slight variation on Lalit's answer, since you want the [outward code](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_postcodes#Outward_code) rather than a fixed substring of the first four characters (which could incude a space and the start of the inward code), you can create a virtual column based on the first word of the value:

```
postcode varchar2(8),
outward_code generated always as
  (substr(postcode, 1, instr(postcode, ' ', 1, 1) - 1))
```

And optionally, but probably if you're using this to search, an index on the virtual column.

This assumes the post codes are formatted properly in the first place. It won't work if you don't always have the space between the outward and inward codes. And to answer your original question, the actual post code should be a `varchar2(8)` column to hold alphanumeric valus up to the maximum size and with the standard format.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e76dbe/1).

Comment: _"This assumes the post codes are formatted properly in the first place."_ This should probably be enforced by a [`CHECK` constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#sthref2913).

Comment: An index on virtual column is equivalent of a function -based index.

Answer (score 2):

> I should be able to easily compare first four characters of each postal code.

Then keep these first four characters in a separate `column`. And `index` this column. You could keep the other characters in different column. Now, if the codes are a mixture of `alphanumeric characters`, then you are left with `VARCHAR2` data type.

Your query predicate would like -

`WHERE post_code_col = substr('N22 5HF', 1, 4)`

Thus the `indexed column post_code_col` would be efficient in `performance`.

On `11g`, you have the option to create a `virtual column`. However, indexing it would be equivalent to a `function-based` index. So I woukd prefer the first way as I suggested above.

It is better to `normalize` the table during the design phase, else the issues would start creeping in later.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should use varchar2 data type because this field will not going to be in mathematical calculations (they should not be int or decimal) and these fields are not big enough (so this should not be text)